# Update google service in genymotion without sign in google play

Tags: genymotion

After installing google services in genymotion need to Update it. Google doesn't support my country and so I can't update it from google play.

Is there any way to update it?

Answer (score 0):

go to [APKMirror](http://www.apkmirror.com) and search for Google Play Store. Download the newest version and drag and drop it into Genymotion.